# MYSQL query - join or loop query

Tags: mysql, join, database-performance

So I am working with a few tables in a database, and I'm wondering the best way to query it.

Here's the setup:

```
EVENTS:
int event_id
varchar event_name
date event_date

ATTENDANCE:
int attendance_id
int event_id (foreign key for EVENTS)
int user_id (foreign key for USERS)
int status

USERS:
int user_id
varchar first_name
varchar last_name
varchar email
```

Pretty much what I was going to do, is have an event (the ID #) that I want to get the attendance for, and then query the attendance table for all records matching that event, then query the users table for all users referenced in attendance as part of that event.

The first thought that came to mind was to first query the database for all attendance entries and get an array, then loop through each record to query the user information. However this seems pretty inefficient and there must be a better way with joins or something of the like. I don't have much experience with joins, so I was wondering if I could get some help.

This is the pseudo code of what I was originally thinking:

```
SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE event_id = eventID
while (row exists):
    SELECT FROM users WHERE user_id = attendanceUserID
    get info export in xml...etc.
```

I don't think this is the best way to do this, so what would be the better way to do it?

Comment: great opportunity to learn about joins; they may be intimidating at first but you will become a natural in no time; [start here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: so you think joins are the best way to go about this?

Comment: That's what join are made for. try `SELECT 
e.event_name, e.event_date,
u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email  
FROM events e 
INNER JOIN attendance a ON a.event_id = e.event_id 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id  = a.user_id ` I just typed it on top of my head, that should give you a direction where to look

Comment: go to w3schools, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp. great tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is "join or loop?" and the technical answer is use a join. What you are describing is what joins are meant to do, combine tables on conditions.

"select from ... (select more)" isn't the way to go about it. Consider the idea really of "what do these two tables have that connects them in a totally reliable and identifiable way? The note in the above comment is spot on.

However, as an "old man", the question isn't quite as straightforward. Everything is a question of time, yours and the machine's. So ask yourself this: imagine method A is 100 times more efficient than method B. But, you already know how to do method B. AND... the difference is 0.02 milliseconds versus 2 milliseconds. (Let's just say you have a small data set, and a fast machine.) If you can code up method B in three minutes and get on with your project, that might be good. Especially if there's a deadline. Because everything is easier with a working example to start from, even if implemented in a different way. It gives you something to test the NEW method that you're just learning against. Lots of people chase efficiency before they even know if it would even matter or not.

Get things working first, make them faster second. (Of course, don't paint yourself into a horrible design corner. You haven't though, the database is fine, you're just looking at different ways of getting info out of it.)